# Tensorrt wit MNIST sample proyect do not fails inference validation

Tags: mnist, tensorrt

I am trying to build and run the tensorrt MNIST sample proyect (https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/release/6.0/samples/opensource/sampleMNIST) but when I run it, it fails the inference because it always predict the same output (digit 8).

Here I show how I run the application and the output I get.

Thanks,
Esteban

```
poncos@electron:~/CLionProjects/tensorrt$ ./bin/sampleMNIST --datadir=./resources
&&&& RUNNING TensorRT.sample_mnist # ./bin/sampleMNIST --datadir=./resources
[08/25/2019-23:57:46] [I] Building and running a GPU inference engine for MNIST
[08/25/2019-23:57:47] [I] [TRT] Detected 1 inputs and 1 output network tensors.
[08/25/2019-23:57:47] [I] Input:
--:.:===-=.--=====.... .:..:
 .::                        



                    @@@     
                   @@@@@    
                 @@@@@@@    
            @  @@@@@ @@@    
           @@@@@@@@  @@@    
            @@@@@    @@@    
             @@@@    @@@    
              @@@    @@@    
               @     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                     @@@    
                      @     





[08/25/2019-23:57:47] [I] Output:
0: 
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: **********
9: 

&&&& FAILED TensorRT.sample_mnist # ./bin/sampleMNIST --datadir=./resources
poncos@electron:~/CLionProjects/tensorrt$
```

Comment: Which files do you have inside your `./resources` directory? Are they .pgm files?  What are the sizes? It's best if you use the image size of the Mnist dataset, since this example in particular doesn't have dynamic resizing.

Comment: Hi @bpinaya in the resources folder I have the three files with the model (mnist.caffemodel, mnist.prototxt, mnist_mean.binaryproto) and the ten pgm files, each one 28x28 pixels, which I think it is the size used by the mnist dataset.